# how can I listen to an unknown request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, request, httprequest

my Nodejs Server will be reciveing the following post request :

`POST /v1/devices/deviceID/registrations/typeID/serial#`

where deviceID,typeID,serial# are variables and not the same

I did use the following to figure out what these variables are , however this is not the optimal solution I'm looking for because there are  other requests that have the same start like  `/v1/devices/registrations/`

```
app.post("/v1/devices/*", function (req, res) {
});
```

So the main question is how can I identify that when you receive a post request with the following structure `/v1/devices/deviceID/registrations/typeID/serial#` , store the values of DeviceID , typeID and serial#

also how can I do the same for these 2 requests , also note that device and type ids are variables

```
if the following is requested 
GET /v1/devices/<deviceID>/registrations/<typeID>
do something 
else if 
GET /v1/devices/<deviceID>/registrations/<typeID>?passesUpdatedSince=<tag>
do something else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not mentioned, I am assuming you are using ExpressJS with Node and if you are not using [Express](http://expressjs.com/) you can easily achieve this with it.

You can easily use the built in functionality of route parameters.

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

I.e.

```
app.post("/v1/devices/:deviceID/registrations/:typeID/:serial", function (req, res) {
  var deviceId = req.params.deviceId;
  var typeId = req.params.typeId;
  var serial = req.params.serial;
});
```

So you don't need to have a catch all you can design specific routes for each request you have.

You can use the exact same approach for your second example and can access the query params within your route for example `req.query.passesUpdatedSince`

Comment: how can I make it differentiate between  the one which has the query and the one that doesn't ?

Comment: You could simply add a check to the top of the route so `if (!req.query.passesUpdatedSince)`